# Can I bring a visual flow chart for complex magic cards to events?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel, mtg-professional-rel

I was reading the card [Chains of Mephistopheles](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=chains%20of%20mephistopheles) and I found these great [flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nImv9.jpg) [charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeLTN.png) for how it's replacement effect works. Would I be allowed to bring a simple flow chart like that to a sanctioned event? Would this change if the event was Competitive or Professional REL?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "REL level 2"? I assume you mean Competitive REL, because that is the middle in terms of strictness out of the three levels.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Sorry I was mixing up judge levels and REL levels. That is correct that I meant Competitive and Professional REL. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot refer to pre-made notes or diagrams like that during matches in a tournament. The [Magic Tournament Rules](https://wpn.wizards.com/en/document/magic-gathering-tournament-rules) section 2.11 says the following:

> Players are allowed to take written notes during a match and may refer to those notes while that match is in progress. At the beginning of a match, each player’s note sheet must be empty and must remain visible throughout the match. Players do not have to explain or reveal notes to other players. Judges may ask to see a player’s notes and/or request that the player explain their notes.
>
> **Players may not refer to other notes, including notes from previous matches, during games.**